# Why does Python Glue Job throw a KeyError for my Job parameter?

Tags: python, aws-glue

I have defined a simple Glue Job of type Python Shell:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [
  'test-parameter'
])

value = args["test-parameter"]
print(f'value = {value}')
```

I am trying to pass the following Job parameter:

- Key: `--test-parameter`
- Value: `hello world`

When I run this Glue Job, I get the following error:

> KeyError: 'test-parameter'

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `getResolvedOptions` translates hyphens to underscores in parameter names. I confirmed this by adding some logging:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

print(f'sys.argv = {sys.argv}')

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [
  'test-parameter'
])

print(f'args = {args}')

value = args["test-parameter"]
print(f'value = {value}')
```

In the CloudWatch logs, I see:

- `sys.argv = ['--test-parameter', 'hello world', ...]`
- `args = {'test_parameter': 'hello world'}`

To resolve this issue, I changed the Job parameter to use underscores instead of hyphens. (Note you still need the two leading hyphens...so `--test_parameter` instead of `--test-parameter`.)